# Can't start docker on Windows 10 with VirtualBox 5.1.8 r11374

Tags: windows, docker, virtualbox

Just can't start Docker on Windows 10.
VT-x is on, I've re-installed Docker, Virtualbox, re-configured the NAT network device on Virtualbox, reconfigured the whole Virtualbox settings, I've re-installed whatever called the `VBoxDrv.inf`, I've rebooted almost 1000 times over, but I can't fix this issue.
I have no idea what's going on.

Here's my VBoxHardening.log

```
1730.2140: Log file opened: 5.1.8r111374 g_hStartupLog=000000000000013c g_uNtVerCombined=0xa03fab00
1730.2140: \SystemRoot\System32\ntdll.dll:
1730.2140:     CreationTime:    2017-11-15T00:34:22.140964500Z
1730.2140:     LastWriteTime:   2017-10-25T04:37:21.227931100Z
1730.2140:     ChangeTime:      2017-11-15T05:18:19.608963500Z
1730.2140:     FileAttributes:  0x20
1730.2140:     Size:            0x1dd100
1730.2140:     NT Headers:      0xe0
1730.2140:     Timestamp:       0x493793ea
1730.2140:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
1730.2140:     Timestamp:       0x493793ea
1730.2140:     Image Version:   10.0
1730.2140:     SizeOfImage:     0x1e0000 (1966080)
1730.2140:     Resource Dir:    0x174000 LB 0x6a1d8
1730.2140:     ProductName:     Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
1730.2140:     ProductVersion:  10.0.16299.64
1730.2140:     FileVersion:     10.0.16299.64 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
1730.2140:     FileDescription: NT Layer DLL
1730.2140: \SystemRoot\System32\kernel32.dll:
1730.2140:     CreationTime:    2017-09-29T13:42:04.954227600Z
1730.2140:     LastWriteTime:   2017-09-29T13:42:04.954227600Z
1730.2140:     ChangeTime:      2017-11-10T06:51:05.986969400Z
1730.2140:     FileAttributes:  0x20
1730.2140:     Size:            0xab868
1730.2140:     NT Headers:      0xe8
1730.2140:     Timestamp:       0xc2cf900
1730.2140:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
1730.2140:     Timestamp:       0xc2cf900
1730.2140:     Image Version:   10.0
1730.2140:     SizeOfImage:     0xae000 (712704)
1730.2140:     Resource Dir:    0xac000 LB 0x520
1730.2140:     ProductName:     Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
1730.2140:     ProductVersion:  10.0.16299.15
1730.2140:     FileVersion:     10.0.16299.15 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
1730.2140:     FileDescription: Windows NT BASE API Client DLL
1730.2140: \SystemRoot\System32\KernelBase.dll:
1730.2140:     CreationTime:    2017-09-29T13:41:43.124345500Z
1730.2140:     LastWriteTime:   2017-09-29T13:41:43.124345500Z
1730.2140:     ChangeTime:      2017-11-10T06:51:06.533874600Z
1730.2140:     FileAttributes:  0x20
1730.2140:     Size:            0x266000
1730.2140:     NT Headers:      0xf0
1730.2140:     Timestamp:       0x4736733c
1730.2140:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
1730.2140:     Timestamp:       0x4736733c
1730.2140:     Image Version:   10.0
1730.2140:     SizeOfImage:     0x266000 (2514944)
1730.2140:     Resource Dir:    0x245000 LB 0x548
1730.2140:     ProductName:     Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
1730.2140:     ProductVersion:  10.0.16299.15
1730.2140:     FileVersion:     10.0.16299.15 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
1730.2140:     FileDescription: Windows NT BASE API Client DLL
1730.2140: \SystemRoot\System32\apisetschema.dll:
1730.2140:     CreationTime:    2017-09-29T13:42:07.095026600Z
1730.2140:     LastWriteTime:   2017-09-29T13:42:07.095026600Z
1730.2140:     ChangeTime:      2017-11-10T06:50:59.486619300Z
1730.2140:     FileAttributes:  0x20
1730.2140:     Size:            0x1b398
1730.2140:     NT Headers:      0xc8
1730.2140:     Timestamp:       0xf30abf31
1730.2140:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
1730.2140:     Timestamp:       0xf30abf31
1730.2140:     Image Version:   10.0
1730.2140:     SizeOfImage:     0x1c000 (114688)
1730.2140:     Resource Dir:    0x1b000 LB 0x408
1730.2140:     ProductName:     Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
1730.2140:     ProductVersion:  10.0.16299.15
1730.2140:     FileVersion:     10.0.16299.15 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
1730.2140:     FileDescription: ApiSet Schema DLL
1730.2140: NtOpenDirectoryObject failed on \Driver: 0xc0000022
1730.2140: supR3HardenedWinFindAdversaries: 0x0
1730.2140: supR3HardenedWinInitAppBin(0x0): '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox'
1730.2140: Calling main()
1730.2140: SUPR3HardenedMain: pszProgName=VBoxHeadless fFlags=0x0
1730.2140: supR3HardenedWinInitAppBin(0x0): '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox'
1730.2140: SUPR3HardenedMain: Respawn #1
1730.2140: System32:  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32
1730.2140: WinSxS:    \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\WinSxS
1730.2140: KnownDllPath: C:\WINDOWS\System32
1730.2140: '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe' has no imports
1730.2140: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -0 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe)
1730.2140: supR3HardNtEnableThreadCreation:
1730.2140: supR3HardNtDisableThreadCreation: pvLdrInitThunk=00007ff8fed791b0 pvNtTerminateThread=00007ff8feda0890
1730.2140: supR3HardenedWinDoReSpawn(1): New child 3da4.3b20 [kernel32].
1730.2140: supR3HardNtChildGatherData: PebBaseAddress=0000000001165000 cbPeb=0x388
1730.2140: supR3HardNtPuChFindNtdll: uNtDllParentAddr=00007ff8fed00000 uNtDllChildAddr=00007ff8fed00000
1730.2140: supR3HardenedWinSetupChildInit: uLdrInitThunk=00007ff8fed791b0
1730.2140: supR3HardenedWinSetupChildInit: Start child.
1730.2140: supR3HardNtChildWaitFor: Found expected request 0 (PurifyChildAndCloseHandles) after 1 ms.
1730.2140: supR3HardNtChildPurify: Startup delay kludge #1/0: 261 ms, 29 sleeps
1730.2140: supHardNtVpScanVirtualMemory: enmKind=CHILD_PURIFICATION
1730.2140:  *0000000000000000-ffffffffff00ffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1730.2140:  *0000000000ff0000-0000000000febfff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0040000
1730.2140:   0000000000ff4000-0000000000fe7fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1730.2140:  *0000000001000000-0000000000e9afff 0x0000/0x0004 0x0020000
1730.2140:   0000000001165000-0000000001161fff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
1730.2140:   0000000001168000-00000000010cffff 0x0000/0x0004 0x0020000
1730.2140:  *0000000001200000-00000000011dffff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
1730.2140:  *0000000001220000-0000000001206fff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0040000
1730.2140:   0000000001239000-0000000001231fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1730.2140:  *0000000001240000-0000000001144fff 0x0000/0x0004 0x0020000
1730.2140:   000000000133b000-0000000001337fff 0x0104/0x0004 0x0020000
1730.2140:   000000000133e000-000000000133bfff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
1730.2140:  *0000000001340000-000000000133efff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
1730.2140:   0000000001341000-ffffffff826a1fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1730.2140:  *000000007ffe0000-000000007ffdefff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0020000
1730.2140:  *000000007ffe1000-000000007ffd1fff 0x0000/0x0002 0x0020000
1730.2140:   000000007fff0000-ffff800aa2b1ffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1730.2140:  *00007ff65d4c0000-00007ff65d48cfff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0040000
1730.2140:   00007ff65d4f3000-00007ff65c6d5fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1730.2140:  *00007ff65e310000-00007ff65e310fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1730.2140:   00007ff65e311000-00007ff65e37ffff 0x0020/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1730.2140:   00007ff65e380000-00007ff65e380fff 0x0080/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1730.2140:   00007ff65e381000-00007ff65e3c5fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1730.2140:   00007ff65e3c6000-00007ff65e3c6fff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1730.2140:   00007ff65e3c7000-00007ff65e3c7fff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1730.2140:   00007ff65e3c8000-00007ff65e3ccfff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1730.2140:   00007ff65e3cd000-00007ff65e3cdfff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1730.2140:   00007ff65e3ce000-00007ff65e3cefff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1730.2140:   00007ff65e3cf000-00007ff65e3d2fff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1730.2140:   00007ff65e3d3000-00007ff65e41afff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1730.2140:   00007ff65e41b000-00007ff3bdb35fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1730.2140:  *00007ff8fed00000-00007ff8fed00fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1730.2140:   00007ff8fed01000-00007ff8fee12fff 0x0020/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1730.2140:   00007ff8fee13000-00007ff8fee58fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1730.2140:   00007ff8fee59000-00007ff8fee60fff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1730.2140:   00007ff8fee61000-00007ff8fee6efff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1730.2140:   00007ff8fee6f000-00007ff8fee6ffff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1730.2140:   00007ff8fee70000-00007ff8fee72fff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1730.2140:   00007ff8fee73000-00007ff8feedffff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1730.2140:  *00007ff8feee0000-00007ff8feedbfff 0x0040/0x0040 0x0020000 !!
1730.2140: supHardNtVpFreeOrReplacePrivateExecMemory: Freeing exec mem at 00007ff8feee0000 (LB 0x4000, 00007ff8feee0000 LB 0x4000)
1730.2140: supHardNtVpFreeOrReplacePrivateExecMemory: Free attempt #1 succeeded: 0x0 [00007ff8feee0000/00007ff8feee0000 LB 0/0x4000]
1730.2140: supHardNtVpFreeOrReplacePrivateExecMemory: QVM after free 0: [0000000000000000]/00007ff8feee0000 LB 0x701100000 s=0x10000 ap=0x0rp=0x3144322d00000001
1730.2140:   00007ff8feee4000-00007ff1fdde7fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1730.2140:  *00007ffffffe0000-00007ffffffcffff 0x0001/0x0002 0x0020000
1730.2140: VBoxHeadless.exe: timestamp 0x58062715 (rc=VINF_SUCCESS)
1730.2140: '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe' has no imports
1730.2140: '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll' has no imports
1730.2140: ntdll.dll: Differences in section #1 (.text) between file and memory:
1730.2140:   00007ff8feda34e0 / 0x00a34e0: 4c != e9
1730.2140:   00007ff8feda34e1 / 0x00a34e1: 8b != 1b
1730.2140:   00007ff8feda34e2 / 0x00a34e2: d1 != cb
1730.2140:   00007ff8feda34e3 / 0x00a34e3: b8 != 13
1730.2140:   00007ff8feda34e4 / 0x00a34e4: b6 != 00
1730.2140:   Restored 0x2000 bytes of original file content at 00007ff8feda31be
1730.2140: supR3HardNtChildPurify: cFixes=2 g_fSupAdversaries=0x80000000
1730.2140: supR3HardNtChildPurify: Startup delay kludge #1/1: 520 ms, 58 sleeps
1730.2140: supHardNtVpScanVirtualMemory: enmKind=CHILD_PURIFICATION
1730.2140:  *0000000000000000-ffffffffff00ffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1730.2140:  *0000000000ff0000-0000000000febfff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0040000
1730.2140:   0000000000ff4000-0000000000fe7fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1730.2140:  *0000000001000000-0000000000e9afff 0x0000/0x0004 0x0020000
1730.2140:   0000000001165000-0000000001161fff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
1730.2140:   0000000001168000-00000000010cffff 0x0000/0x0004 0x0020000
1730.2140:  *0000000001200000-00000000011dffff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
1730.2140:  *0000000001220000-0000000001206fff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0040000
1730.2140:   0000000001239000-0000000001231fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1730.2140:  *0000000001240000-0000000001144fff 0x0000/0x0004 0x0020000
1730.2140:   000000000133b000-0000000001337fff 0x0104/0x0004 0x0020000
1730.2140:   000000000133e000-000000000133bfff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
1730.2140:  *0000000001340000-000000000133efff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
1730.2140:   0000000001341000-ffffffff826a1fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1730.2140:  *000000007ffe0000-000000007ffdefff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0020000
1730.2140:  *000000007ffe1000-000000007ffd1fff 0x0000/0x0002 0x0020000
1730.2140:   000000007fff0000-ffff800aa2b1ffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1730.2140:  *00007ff65d4c0000-00007ff65d48cfff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0040000
1730.2140:   00007ff65d4f3000-00007ff65c6d5fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1730.2140:  *00007ff65e310000-00007ff65e310fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1730.2140:   00007ff65e311000-00007ff65e37ffff 0x0020/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1730.2140:   00007ff65e380000-00007ff65e380fff 0x0040/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1730.2140:   00007ff65e381000-00007ff65e3c5fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1730.2140:   00007ff65e3c6000-00007ff65e3d2fff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1730.2140:   00007ff65e3d3000-00007ff65e41afff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1730.2140:   00007ff65e41b000-00007ff3bdb35fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1730.2140:  *00007ff8fed00000-00007ff8fed00fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1730.2140:   00007ff8fed01000-00007ff8fee12fff 0x0020/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1730.2140:   00007ff8fee13000-00007ff8fee58fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1730.2140:   00007ff8fee59000-00007ff8fee5cfff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1730.2140:   00007ff8fee5d000-00007ff8fee60fff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1730.2140:   00007ff8fee61000-00007ff8fee6efff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1730.2140:   00007ff8fee6f000-00007ff8fee6ffff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1730.2140:   00007ff8fee70000-00007ff8fee72fff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1730.2140:   00007ff8fee73000-00007ff8feedffff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1730.2140:   00007ff8feee0000-00007ff1fdddffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1730.2140:  *00007ffffffe0000-00007ffffffcffff 0x0001/0x0002 0x0020000
1730.2140: supR3HardNtChildPurify: Done after 884 ms and 2 fixes (loop #1). 3da4.3b20: Log file opened: 5.1.8r111374 g_hStartupLog=0000000000000008 g_uNtVerCombined=0xa03fab00 3da4.3b20:
supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: uNtDllAddr=00007ff8fed00000g_uNtVerCombined=0xa03fab00
1730.2140: supR3HardNtEnableThreadCreation: 3da4.3b20: ntdll.dll: timestamp 0x493793ea (rc=VINF_SUCCESS) 3da4.3b20: New simple heap: #10000000001450000 LB 0x400000 (for 1966080 allocation) 3da4.3b20:
supR3HardenedWinInitAppBin(0x0): '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox' 3da4.3b20: System32: 
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32 3da4.3b20: WinSxS:   
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\WinSxS 3da4.3b20: KnownDllPath:
C:\WINDOWS\System32 3da4.3b20: supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: Opening
vboxdrv stub... 3da4.3b20: supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: Restoring
LdrInitializeThunk... 3da4.3b20: supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: Returning
to LdrInitializeThunk... 3da4.3b20: Registered Dll notification
callback with NTDLL. 3da4.3b20: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: ->
0 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll) 3da4.3b20:
supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheInsert:
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll 3da4.3b20:
supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll:
pName=C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL (Input=KERNEL32.DLL,
rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0xffffffff
pwszSearchPath=0000000000004001:<flags[calling] 3da4.3b20:
supR3HardenedDllNotificationCallback: load   00007ff8fac50000 LB
0x00266000 C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll [fFlags=0x0] 3da4.3b20:
supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -0
(\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll) 3da4.3b20:
supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheInsert:
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll 3da4.3b20:
supR3HardenedDllNotificationCallback: load   00007ff8fcd50000 LB
0x000ae000 C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL [fFlags=0x0] 3da4.3b20:
supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll [lacks
WinVerifyTrust] 3da4.3b20: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns
rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ff8fcd50000 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL'
3da4.3b20: supR3HardenedDllNotificationCallback: load  
00007ff65e310000 LB 0x0010b000 C:\Program
Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe [fFlags=0x0] 3da4.3b20:
'\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program
Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe' has no imports 3da4.3b20:
supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -0
(\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program
Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe) 3da4.3b20:
supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheInsert: \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program
Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe 3da4.3b20:
supR3HardNtDisableThreadCreation: pvLdrInitThunk=00007ff8fed791b0
pvNtTerminateThread=00007ff8feda0890
    1730.2140: supR3HardNtChildWaitFor: Found expected request 1 (CloseEvents) after 166 ms. 3da4.3b20: \SystemRoot\System32\ntdll.dll:
3da4.3b20:     CreationTime:    2017-11-15T00:34:22.140964500Z
3da4.3b20:     LastWriteTime:   2017-10-25T04:37:21.227931100Z
3da4.3b20:     ChangeTime:      2017-11-15T05:18:19.608963500Z
3da4.3b20:     FileAttributes:  0x20 3da4.3b20:     Size:           
0x1dd100 3da4.3b20:     NT Headers:      0xe0 3da4.3b20:    
Timestamp:       0x493793ea 3da4.3b20:     Machine:         0x8664 -
amd64 3da4.3b20:     Timestamp:       0x493793ea 3da4.3b20:     Image
Version:   10.0 3da4.3b20:     SizeOfImage:     0x1e0000 (1966080)
3da4.3b20:     Resource Dir:    0x174000 LB 0x6a1d8 3da4.3b20:    
ProductName:     Microsoft® Windows® Operating System 3da4.3b20:    
ProductVersion:  10.0.16299.64 3da4.3b20:     FileVersion:    
10.0.16299.64 (WinBuild.160101.0800) 3da4.3b20:     FileDescription: NT Layer DLL 3da4.3b20: \SystemRoot\System32\kernel32.dll: 3da4.3b20: 
CreationTime:    2017-09-29T13:42:04.954227600Z 3da4.3b20:    
LastWriteTime:   2017-09-29T13:42:04.954227600Z 3da4.3b20:    
ChangeTime:      2017-11-10T06:51:05.986969400Z 3da4.3b20:    
FileAttributes:  0x20 3da4.3b20:     Size:            0xab868
3da4.3b20:     NT Headers:      0xe8 3da4.3b20:     Timestamp:      
0xc2cf900 3da4.3b20:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64 3da4.3b20:   
Timestamp:       0xc2cf900 3da4.3b20:     Image Version:   10.0
3da4.3b20:     SizeOfImage:     0xae000 (712704) 3da4.3b20:    
Resource Dir:    0xac000 LB 0x520 3da4.3b20:     ProductName:    
Microsoft® Windows® Operating System 3da4.3b20:     ProductVersion: 
10.0.16299.15 3da4.3b20:     FileVersion:     10.0.16299.15 (WinBuild.160101.0800) 3da4.3b20:     FileDescription: Windows NT BASE
API Client DLL 3da4.3b20: \SystemRoot\System32\KernelBase.dll:
3da4.3b20:     CreationTime:    2017-09-29T13:41:43.124345500Z
3da4.3b20:     LastWriteTime:   2017-09-29T13:41:43.124345500Z
3da4.3b20:     ChangeTime:      2017-11-10T06:51:06.533874600Z
3da4.3b20:     FileAttributes:  0x20 3da4.3b20:     Size:           
0x266000 3da4.3b20:     NT Headers:      0xf0 3da4.3b20:    
Timestamp:       0x4736733c 3da4.3b20:     Machine:         0x8664 -
amd64 3da4.3b20:     Timestamp:       0x4736733c 3da4.3b20:     Image
Version:   10.0 3da4.3b20:     SizeOfImage:     0x266000 (2514944)
3da4.3b20:     Resource Dir:    0x245000 LB 0x548 3da4.3b20:    
ProductName:     Microsoft® Windows® Operating System 3da4.3b20:    
ProductVersion:  10.0.16299.15 3da4.3b20:     FileVersion:    
10.0.16299.15 (WinBuild.160101.0800) 3da4.3b20:     FileDescription: Windows NT BASE API Client DLL 3da4.3b20:
\SystemRoot\System32\apisetschema.dll: 3da4.3b20:     CreationTime:   
2017-09-29T13:42:07.095026600Z 3da4.3b20:     LastWriteTime:  
2017-09-29T13:42:07.095026600Z 3da4.3b20:     ChangeTime:     
2017-11-10T06:50:59.486619300Z 3da4.3b20:     FileAttributes:  0x20
3da4.3b20:     Size:            0x1b398 3da4.3b20:     NT Headers:    
0xc8 3da4.3b20:     Timestamp:       0xf30abf31 3da4.3b20:    
Machine:         0x8664 - amd64 3da4.3b20:     Timestamp:      
0xf30abf31 3da4.3b20:     Image Version:   10.0 3da4.3b20:    
SizeOfImage:     0x1c000 (114688) 3da4.3b20:     Resource Dir:   
0x1b000 LB 0x408 3da4.3b20:     ProductName:     Microsoft® Windows®
Operating System 3da4.3b20:     ProductVersion:  10.0.16299.15
3da4.3b20:     FileVersion:     10.0.16299.15 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
3da4.3b20:     FileDescription: ApiSet Schema DLL 3da4.3b20:
NtOpenDirectoryObject failed on \Driver: 0xc0000022 3da4.3b20:
supR3HardenedWinFindAdversaries: 0x0 3da4.3b20:
supR3HardenedWinInitAppBin(0x0): '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program
Files\Oracle\VirtualBox' 3da4.3b20: Calling main() 3da4.3b20:
SUPR3HardenedMain: pszProgName=VBoxHeadless fFlags=0x0 3da4.3b20:
supR3HardenedWinInitAppBin(0x0): '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program
Files\Oracle\VirtualBox' 3da4.3b20: '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program
Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe' has no imports 3da4.3b20:
supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -0
(\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program
Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe) 3da4.3b20:
SUPR3HardenedMain: Respawn #2 3da4.3b20:
supR3HardNtEnableThreadCreation: 3da4.3b20:
'\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll' has no imports
3da4.3b20: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -0
(\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll) 3da4.3b20:
supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheInsert:
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll 3da4.3b20:
supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\WINDOWS\System32\ntdll.dll
(Input=ntdll.dll, rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0
pwszSearchPath=0000000000000801:<flags[calling] 3da4.3b20:
supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0
hMod=00007ff8fed00000 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\ntdll.dll' 3da4.3b20: Error
-104 in supR3HardenedWinReSpawn! (enmWhat=5) 3da4.3b20: Error relaunching VirtualBox VM process: 5 Command line:
'60eaff78-4bdd-042d-2e72-669728efd737-suplib-3rdchild --comment
default --startvm 1fa72876-de12-4062-a84e-3a961a8a4872 --vrde config
--sup-hardening-log=C:\Users\~\.docker\machine\machines\default\default\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'
1730.2140: supR3HardNtChildWaitFor[1]: Quitting: ExitCode=0x1 (rcNtWait=0x0, rcNt1=0x0, rcNt2=0x103, rcNt3=0x103, 100 ms, the end);
```

Comment: Do you have the Hyper-V feature active in your Windows 10?

Comment: @VonC No, I'm using Windows 10 Home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by reinstalling the VirtualBox and install Ubuntu virtual machine.